# Rotate the encryption key on MariaDB 10.5 for innodb tables

Tags: encryption, mariadb, innodb

I implemented data in rest encryption on MariaDB 10.5 using the plugin file_key_management.so.

Here is my current configuration:

```
    plugin_dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin
    plugin_load_add = file_key_management.so
    loose_file_key_management_filename = /etc/mysql/keyfile.enc
    loose_file_key_management_filekey = FILE:/etc/mysql/keyfile.key
    loose_file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CTR
    encrypt_binlog = ON
    encrypt_tmp_disk_tables = ON
    encrypt_tmp_files = ON

    innodb_encrypt_tables = FORCE
    innodb_encrypt_log = ON
    innodb_encryption_threads = 4
    innodb_encrypt_temporary_tables = ON
    innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age = 1
    innodb_encryption_rotation_iops = 3000
```

I was able to rotate the encryption key for all tables except for **innodb_system**

```
    MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT NAME,CURRENT_KEY_ID  FROM information_schema.INNODB_TABLESPACES_ENCRYPTION where ENCRYPTION_SCHEME='1' and NAME like "%innodb%" \G
     *************************** 1. row ***************************
        NAME: innodb_system
        CURRENT_KEY_ID: 1
     *************************** 2. row ***************************
        NAME: mysql/innodb_table_stats
        CURRENT_KEY_ID: 3
     *************************** 3. row ***************************
        NAME: mysql/innodb_index_stats
        CURRENT_KEY_ID: 3
```

Using the same query I was not able to rotate the key

```
    MariaDB [(none)]> alter table innodb_system encryption_key_id=3;
    ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
```

I found some documentation on how to rotate on Mysql and if I understood correctly this is like a master key for innodb.

```
    mysql> ALTER INSTANCE ROTATE INNODB MASTER KEY;
```

Which it does not work.

How can I rotate the key ?

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

Before doing anything to a `TABLE` (such as `ALTER`), you must specify which database it is in (eg, such as with a `USE`).

(There may be further mistakes.)

Comment: Other entrances in the information_schema.INNODB_TABLESPACES_ENCRYPTION table comes along with the database Eg:  mysql/innodb_table_stats but not the  innodb_system.